# Can I leave some index values out of the function inside the for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I want the values 2, 4, 6 and 8 not to be used in the for loop. Can I use the seq() function for this?

My codes:

```
my_func <- function(x) {
  a <- 1/((x-2)*(x-4)*(x-6)*(x-8))
  print(a)
}


for (i in 1:10) {
  my_func(i)
}
```

As you noticed, it would be more appropriate to skip some values by using `seq(from = 2, to = 8, by = 2)`

Comment: `for (i in seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 2))` or `for (i in (x <- 1:10)[x %% 2 != 0])`?

Comment: `for (i in (1:100)[-c(2,4,6,8)])`?

Answer (score 0):

In `R` we use `*apply`-functions instead of explicit loops. For instance, you might use `seq()`:

```r
my_func = \(x) { 1L / ( (x-2L) * (x-4L) * (x-6L) * (x-8L) ) }
vapply(seq(1L, 10L, 2L), my_func, numeric(1L)) # or use lapply
```

gives

```r
[1]  0.00952381 -0.06666667  0.11111111 -0.06666667  0.00952381
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of `1:10` not as a slice or range but as a shorthand for `seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1)`, something that creates a vector:

```r
(s1 <- 1:10)
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
for (i in s1) {
  message(i, " ", appendLF = FALSE)
}
#> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

From there, just adjust your loop input vector as you see fit, e.g:

```r
(s2 <- seq(from = 2, to = 8, by = 2))
#> [1] 2 4 6 8
s1[!s1 %in% s2]
#> [1]  1  3  5  7  9 10

for (i in s1[!s1 %in% s2]) {
  message(i, " ", appendLF = FALSE)
}
#> 1 3 5 7 9 10

# or :
setdiff(s1, s2)
#> [1]  1  3  5  7  9 10
for (i in setdiff(s1, s2)) {
  message(i, " ", appendLF = FALSE)
}
#> 1 3 5 7 9 10
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>